# Find first element in array and place it at the beginning

Tags: php, sorting

Given the following array:

$arr = array ([0] => "apple", [1] => "pineapple", [2] => "fruit");

How can I place "fruit", if exists in the array, to the first index, pushing the others forward?

Expected result:

```
$arr = array ([0] => "fruit", [1] => "apple", [2] => "pineapple");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `array_search()` and `array_unshift()`

```
<?php
 $arr = array ("apple","pineapple","fruit");
 $fruit_key =  array_search('fruit', $arr);
 if($fruit_key){
    $fruit_value = $arr[$fruit_key];
    unset($arr[$fruit_key]); 
    array_unshift($arr, $fruit_value);
    print_r($arr);    
  }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => fruit
        [1] => apple 
        [2] => pineapple
      )
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/bir6i